# How do you access the HTTP basic authentication username from perl?

Tags: perl, cgi, basic-authentication

I need to get the remote user name in my CGI script. Where do I find that? I want to display that name on the page that I return.

Comment: I have a cgi script that requires HTTP basic auth, and I need to display that username on the page.

Comment: Are you using a module to help you with the cgi stuff?, or are you coding it all yourself from scratch?

Comment: Shudder: If you have a CGI script, why do you rely on basic auth? How do you manage a logout then?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Under the CGI spec, the HTTP-auth user name will be in the environment variable `REMOTE_USER`. In Perl you can get this via `$ENV{REMOTE_USER}`.

You can find descriptions of all the standard CGI environment variables, including `REMOTE_USER`, in section 4 of [RFC 3875](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875).

Comment: Then, how can get password?

Answer (score 14):

The `remote_user()` method in the [CGI module](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html).

If you're not using the CGI module, the environment variable REMOTE_USER: `$ENV{REMOTE_USER}`