# How to verify/change git user info?

Tags: git

In git you have to set a global `user.name` and `user.email`. These will be used as author info in the shared git repository which is served via Apache with Ldap authentication.

The problem is that I want to use this authentication process not just for deciding if a user can or not to push but also to ensure that I have the correct author in the git repository.

How would something like this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does pushing work? Through a CGI script? If so, there will be an environment variable containing the username called `REMOTE_USER` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2539633/492364)). Put **[an `update` hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)** in your repository that checks whether all the new commits are allowed for the user specified in that variable.

Note that a drawback of this approach is that if multiple people have pushed something to branch A, no normal developer can push all of those changes over to `master` or so, too, because some of the commits don't belong to him. You might want to check whether the new commits already exist on some other branch and, in that case, let them through without a check.